# Wireshark display filter where source address in not an ip-address

Tags: wireshark

I wanted to filter out this line....

```
No. Time            Source              Dest        Protocol Length Info
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
20  111.526875000   CompalIn_dc:d9:3e   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 10.32.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.120
```

I tried...

```
!(ip.src==CompalIn_dc:d9:3e && eth.dst==ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff && arp)
```

But that didnt work as it didnt like the `CompalIn_dc:d9:3e` part for the ip-address. Is there another way to specify the 'Source' if it is not an ip-address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an Ethernet MAC address, not an IP address, so you filter it with `eth.src`, not `ip.src`.  Also, since you're attempting to use the resolved Ethernet address (with the [OUI](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui.txt)), then you'll actually need to use `eth.src_resolved=="CompalIn_dc:d9:3e"`, since `eth.src` is for unresolved MAC addresses.

Keep in mind that the `eth.src_resolved` filter is only available since Wireshark 1.12.0 though, so if you're using an older version of Wireshark, then you'll have to use `eth.src` and the unresolved 6 bytes of the MAC address instead.

You can check for filter availability here: https://wireshark.org/docs/dfref/e/eth.html